# Edits to other people's answers

Tags: discussion, editing

Related to [a previous question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-should-the-policy-on-improving-or-incorperating-other-peoples-solutions-be), but sufficiently different that I think it merits its own discussion.

Now that I've hit 2000 rep I have access to some mod tools, which include the ability to approve or reject edits made by users with less than 1000 rep. There are four outstanding, some of them from a while back.

What should we do with edits like this? I don't seem to have the ability to promote them to answers, so the options are to accept them, reject them, or reject them and summarise the changes in a comment so that the original author can incorporate them or not.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved in terms of edits that improve others' solutions? I just passed on a suggested edit that simply reduced the character count in somebody's golfed code. From the comments below, I can't deduce whether the community decided such edits are OK or not OK. Does rejecting an edit allow one to specify the reason why it's being rejected?

Comment: @COTO, I think the consensus expressed below is that if it was correcting the character count it's ok, but if it was changing the code it isn't. You do get a (very short) custom message to explain the rejection.

Comment: OK. Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I've found to be trickier on CodeGolf.SE than on other sites.

I'll start by dividing the problem into three groups

1. **change only the character count**

   These are relatively easy, just check with George's script.
2. **change the text, but not the solution**

   Substantive edits that don't touch the solution are about the same as on other site. Just check that they really do improve the question in terms of grammar, spelling, usage, clarity, etc.
3. **change the solution**

   This is the place where I'm stuck. When we were playing on Stack Overflow people generally did not edit each others work, but left helpful comments---your third solution comes down to enforcing that approach.

   I started leaving them under the impression that the authors would be see them and take care of it, but I'm not sure that this is the case.

---

*Aside:* The whle topic makes me feel guilty because I've been studiouly ignoring some of these suggested edits.

Comment: On SO people would also create a new answer containing the improvements and mention that this answer was based on so and so's answer. Is there something about this site that is giving people the impression that there should only be one answer for each language?

Comment: I don't really see any point in multiple FooLang answers that all take the same strategy, but I *like* to see several approaches no matter what languages they are implemented in.

Answer (score 5):

Of the three options I've suggested, I favour the third: to add comments summarising the proposed changes for the original authors to deal with. It's not really fair on the people who made the edits, because they won't get any rep, but it's more in line with the way improvements to someone else's answer are proposed in general on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a few proposed edits where **a second, highly related solution is edited into the same answer below the original**.

This can perhaps be OK, or is at least safer, since the original is not touched and there is an "alternate" version which the OP can choose to fold into their original answer via editing?

Dunno, just throwing it out there as an idea, since I didn't see it listed in the other answers here.